# How to make API Gateway to return any status code if no query parameters are detected?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I need to make `API Gateway` return any of the following status codes if any query parameter is detected:

- 400 Bad Request
- 403 Forbidden
- 404 Not found
- 416 Range Not Satisfiable
- 500 Internal server error
- 502 Bad gateway
- 503 Service unavailable
- 504 Gateway timeout

I'm working on an image service that has a `CloudFront Distribution` and some `Lambdas` behind it that process incoming images based on query parameters.
Images are fetched from an `S3 Bucket` and then returned by `Lambda` with edits if any valid query parameter is passed through.

If no query parameter is passed I would like to just return the original image but without uselessly triggering the `Lambda` function, since there are no edits to be applied.

Since I have my `S3 Bucket` **public** and has **Static Site Hosting** enabled I'm looking for a way to bypass `Lambda` triggering and return the original image from `S3` directly in case no query parameters are coming with the request.

According to AWS Docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/high_availability_origin_failover.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html) I can accomplish this with **Origin groups** on the `CloudFront` side by setting up a failover origin to `S3` in case `API Gateway` response status is included within the list I mentioned above.

Forgot to mention even though might not be relevant that I'm using **Lambda Proxy integration** with `API Gateway`

But I can't find any way to make it respond with any of those when query parameters are passed.
Do you have any idea how to manage such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can mark query parameter(s) of your API method as required and assign the request validator to your method, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-validation-set-up.html#api-gateway-request-validation-setup-in-console API returns 400 in case any required parameter is not provided.

AFAIK it is not possible to fail request if no query parameter is passed on Gateway level.

Comment: Yep I was looking into Validation but I need the second option, to fail the request if not query parameters are passed.
I'm looking if it might be possible to do the opposite, failover S3 over Api Gateway if any query param is detected.